# Get only three rows for each type value

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Here is my query:

```
SELECT su.userid                     AS uid,
         su.display_name               AS username,
         su.user_type,
         Ifnull(a.totalinvites, 0)     AS invites,
         Ifnull(a.totalreviews, 0)     AS reviews,
  Ifnull(Round(Ifnull(a.totalreviews, 0) / Ifnull(a.totalinvites, 0) * 100, 2), 0) AS invitereviewper
  FROM   (
          SELECT pi.senderuid  AS sid,
           Count(pi.uid) AS totalinvites,
           Count(CASE
                   WHEN pr.rating = 5 THEN pr.uid
                 end)    AS totalreviews
          FROM   podium_invite AS pi
           LEFT JOIN podium_reviews AS pr
                  ON pi.uid = pr.reviewinvitationuid
          WHERE  ( pi.createdat BETWEEN '2022-06-24' AND '2022-09-22' )
          GROUP  BY pi.senderuid
  ) a
  RIGHT JOIN slides_user_status AS su
   ON su.uid = a.sid
  WHERE  su.user_type IN ( 'type1', 'type2', 'type3' )
      AND su.userid NOT IN ( 5414245, 3773293 )
  UNION
  SELECT su.userid AS uid,
         su.display_name AS username,
         su.user_type,
         Ifnull(Sum(a.totalinvites), 0) AS invites,
         Ifnull(Sum(a.totalreviews), 0) AS reviews,
          Ifnull(Round(
          Ifnull(Sum(a.totalreviews), 0) / Ifnull(Sum(a.totalinvites), 0) * 100, 2), 0) AS
                 invitereviewper
  FROM   (
          SELECT pi.senderuid  AS sid,
                 Count(pi.uid) AS totalinvites,
                 Count(CASE
                         WHEN pr.rating = 5 THEN pr.uid
                       end)    AS totalreviews
          FROM   podium_invite AS pi
                 LEFT JOIN podium_reviews AS pr
                        ON pi.uid = pr.reviewinvitationuid
          WHERE  ( pi.createdat BETWEEN '2022-06-24' AND '2022-09-22')
          GROUP  BY pi.senderuid
          ) a
     RIGHT JOIN slides_user_status AS su
                 ON su.uid = a.sid
          WHERE  su.user_type IN ( 'type1', 'type2', 'type3' )
         AND su.userid IN ( 5414245, 3773293 )
  ORDER  BY `reviews` DESC
  limit 0,9;
```

This query is executing without any errors, however, the problem is out of 9 rows, it is fetching unequal number of each type:

for example, its fetching 5 rows with type1, 3 rows with type2 and 1 rows with type3

I want to have 3rows for each type.

Comment: What is precise MySQL version (the output for `SELECT VERSION();`)?

Comment: *I want to have 3rows for each type.* Enumerate the rows in usertype group then return only those rows whose number is not above 3. Additionally - if some type contains less than 3 rows does the total rows amount should be less than 9 or the query must return more than 3 rows for some another group?

Comment: @Akina it should return at max 3, 0 at minimum for each type.

Comment: What is the version? this is critical for your task.

Comment: remote using maridb 10, local using mysql 8

Comment: Previously, I used to loop it through types, and instead of passing an array of types I used to pass a single value:

```
 WHERE  su.user_type = 'type1'
```

however, I believe, I am just repeating a query, this could be in single query so,

Comment: *remote using maridb 10* Why can't you completely answer this simple question? 10.0 and 10.6 (and even 10.2.2) looks like two different servers - in terms of their capabilities.

Comment: See the tag I added.  It has ways to do it before 8.0/10.2.